# Can you wait for an event (Win32 event) to be reset?

Tags: c#, winapi

I am writing some code that monitors if a 3rd party debug viewer (i.e. DbgView) is running. I can handle a full blown debugger easily with Debugger.IsAttached, but to track DbgView, you need to monitor some events. I am basing my code on this article here: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/outputdebugstring.html

So, right now, I have:

```
            IntPtr h1 = CreateEvent(IntPtr.Zero, false, false, "DBWIN_BUFFER_READY");
            WaitForSingleObject(h1, 0xFFFFFFFF);
            //bool b2 = h1 != IntPtr.Zero;
            CloseHandle(h1);
```

Works great. The code blocks until DbgView starts AND starts capturing. Exactly what I want. Now the problem is, I can't tell when the capturing stops.

Is there any way to check when the event is reset or released or whatever DbgView is doing? Preferably without polling the event in a loop :).

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve? What are you planning to do, when a listener starts listening? Why is it important to know, when a listener stops listening?

Comment: @IInspectable, yes, exactly. I want to know when a listener starts and when a listener stops. Debugger.IsAttached handles debuggers, but listeners like DbgView work a different way, they don't trigger the IsAttached flag. The end game is to only generate diagnostic information when there is somebody listening since it can be expensive. i want to automate this behavior. The above code is a light-weight indicator somebody is listening, but trying to know when they stop.

Comment: Have you evaluated the applicability of [Event Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803.aspx)? It's a robust solution to the problem you are trying to solve, tried and tested, and used throughout the OS.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to check when the event is reset?

No there is not. You can wait for events to be set, but not to be reset. You would need there to be another event on which you can wait.

Having read the article which you link to, there is nothing in that protocol that suggests a way for you to detect the end of capturing.

The event you are waiting on is not designed to be used for the purpose you use it for. This event, and its friend `DBWIN_DATA_READY` are used by debuggers to communicate with `OutputDebugString`.

One consequence of this is that any debugger that captures `OutputDebugString` will create these events. So your current approach will find pretty much any debugger, and not just DbgView.

You existing code looks dubious to me. If the event does not already exist, your code will create it. You will then wait for it to be signaled, which may never happen. You may well never have encountered that because you only ever run with a debugger active. You use a magic constant instead of `INFINITE`, and you perform no error checking at all.

Comment: The code snippet I posted is obviously POC, not production code. Also, Visual Studio doesn't create those. As I mentioned in my post, debuggers work a different way then just a debug viewer like DbgView. Debugger.IsAttached captures debuggers, but not DbgView.

Comment: If any debugger wants to capture OutputDebugString, that's how to do it. So you are sure to get other debuggers that way. None of which detracts from the main thrust, which is simple. You can't wait for events to be reset. That is what you asked right?